# An enum method that returns enums of specific interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, enums, enumeration

I have the following interface

```
public interface DeviceKey {
    String getKey();
}
```

I also have various enums that all extends this interface.

In a class that contains all the enums I want a method that based on a string (key), can return the enum corresponding to this string. The string is related to an enum, but it is not the name. My class and enum could look like this:

```
public class Settings {
    private static final Map<String, DeviceKey> lookupAll = Maps.newHashMap();
    static {
        lookupAll.putAll(SmartSetting.lookup);
        // Plus a lot more similar to these
    }

    public static DeviceKey valueOfAnyKey(String key) {
        return lookupAll.get(key);
    }

    public enum SmartSetting implements DeviceKey {
        STATUS("smart_status");

        private static final Map<String, SmartSetting> lookup = EnumUtil.addAll(SmartSetting.class);
        private final String key;

        SmartEncryptionSetting(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }
    }
}
```

The current implementation of `valueOfAnyKey()` returns DeviceKey which of course is not an enum. What should I do in order to make `valueOfAnyKey()` return an enum of the type DeviceKey?

The EnumUtil:

```
private static class EnumUtil {

    public static <T extends Enum<T> & DeviceKey> Map<String, T> addAll(Class<T> theClass) {
        final Map<String, T> retval = new HashMap<String, T>();
        for(T s : EnumSet.allOf(theClass)) {
            retval.put(s.getKey(), s);
        }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java a method can only return one type. You cannot have it return `DeviceKey` "and" `Enum`

Comment: I choosed this as the correct answer despite the final code was implemented as I wrote in my answer. I did it because looking at the original question, this is the correct answer. It is not possible to get what I was looking for in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
import java.util.*;
interface Key {
    String get();
}
class Enums {
    enum Color implements Key {
        r("foo"), g("bar"), b("baz");
        Color(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }
        public String get() {
            return key;
        }
        final String key;
    }
    enum Day implements Key {
        m("quux"), t("fred"), w("hozer");
        Day(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }
        public String get() {
            return key;
        }
        final String key;
    }
    static final Map<String, Enum> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Enum>();
    static {
        for (Color c : Color.values())
            map.put(c.get(), c);
        for (Day d : Day.values())
            map.put(d.get(), d);
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Enums.Color c : Enums.Color.values())
            System.out.println(c+" "+c.get()+" "+Enums.map.get(c.get()));
        for (Enums.Day d : Enums.Day.values())
            System.out.println(d+" "+d.get()+" "+Enums.map.get(d.get()));
    }
}
```

Comment: That would return an enum, but it would not give access to methods implemented from the DeviceKey interface.

Comment: static final Map<String, Key> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Key>(); // do this instead

Comment: Then it is a Key and it can't be used eg. in a switch statement. What I need is to return an enum of a specific type (my interface). I am starting to think this is not possible, even with generics.

Comment: use the enum and cast it to a key.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after working with this some time a colleague found kind of a solution. There are very few changes to the enum, and also some changes are necessary where the `valueOfAnyKey()` is called.
So now we are able to get a DeviceKey returned which we know is an Enum.

```
public class Settings {
    private static final Map<String, Enum<?>> lookupAll = Maps.newHashMap();
    static {
        lookupAll.putAll(SmartSetting.lookup);
        // Plus a lot more similar to these
    }

    public static <T extends Enum<T> & DeviceKey> T valueOfAnyKey(String name) {
        return (T) lookupAll.get(name);
    }

    public enum SmartSetting implements DeviceKey {
        STATUS("smart_status");

        private static final Map<String, SmartSetting> lookup = EnumUtil.addAll(SmartSetting.class);
        private final String key;

        SmartEncryptionSetting(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }
    }
}
```

Looking up a Setting is now done the following way. Neither IntelliJ nor eclipse has any problem leaving out the `<T>` but the Oracle compiler insists on it being there.

```
T setting = DeviceSetting.<T>valueOfAnyKey("settingName);
```

The `<T>`, should now be defined on method or class level. If it is defined on method level then you will sometimes also experience problems with the Oracle compiler, so it is advisable to add the definition to the class instead.

Either:

```
public class SomeClass <T extends Enum<T> & DeviceKey> {
    ....
}
```

or

```
public class SomeClass {
    public <T extends Enum<T> & DeviceKey> void aMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

After all this, it still leaves us with no clue of what kind of Enum we are getting back, and in order to use `setting` (of type T) we need to cast it using `SmartSetting.class.cast(setting)`.
We have discussed if this actually gives us a better solution than the one suggested by Ray Tayek, which also was our first implementation, and the conclusion is that we provide a little more details on what is returned, but seen from the callers point of view you will always have to do the class cast.